# WKWebView WKWebsiteDataStore getAllCookies Doesn't Return the Session Cookie

Tags: ios, authentication, session-cookies, wkwebview

I just moved our login page from UIWebView to WKWebView and having trouble getting the logged in session cookie.

The method I use is WKWebsiteDataStore **getAllCookies** but usually it returns no cookies at all or an old cookie, preventing the user from getting the logged in cookie. That way the user cannot login to our app.

I want to mention that sometimes it works fine and I get the login session cookie successfully but usually it doesn't work.

Would appreciate any help to fix this annoying issue.

Comment: hi @leonidster, do you have any solution/ workaround yet?

Answer (score 3):

After a week struggling, I found a way to make it works. Posting here in case anyone need.

#1 Have an instance of `processPool` and `wesiteDataStore.nonpersistent()` (make them a global variables if you want to get the Cookies outside of webview didFinish navigation of the same wkWebview)

#2 Create an instance of wkWebviewconfigure with these two:

```
var wkWebviewconfigure: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
wkWebviewconfigure.processPool = myProcessPool
wkWebviewconfigure.websiteDatastore = myWebsiteDatastore // <--- have to be nonpersistent type
```

#3 Generate webview from code with this `wkWebviewconfigure`, assigning `wkWebviewconfigure` to your `wkWebview.configuration` from .xib and storyboard will not work